# Releasing NSArray after parsing NSString correctly in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

I would like to know if the following code leaks:

```
bool IsWordOf(NSString* myString, NSString* myWord)
{
    NSMutableCharacterSet *separators = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
    [separators formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSPredicate *noEmptyStrings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];

    NSArray *parse_array = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];
    parse_array = [parse_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noEmptyStrings];

    //NSLog(@"%@", parse_array);

    bool identicalStringFound = NO;
    for (NSString *someString in parse_array) 
    {
        if( [someString caseInsensitiveCompare:myWord] == NSOrderedSame )
        {
            identicalStringFound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    return identicalStringFound;    
}
```

Must I release all the objects of the array ([parse_array releaseAllObjects]) and then release it ([parse array release])?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you didn't allocate it or retain parse_array, so you must not release it.

More generally, you're not responsible for releasing objects stored in an array, or any other objects of which you haven't explicitly taken ownership (via +alloc, -retain, -copy, +new...). If the array retained the objects, the array is responsible for properly releasing them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not leak.

Also, your code could be compacted.  I find it odd that you're using `NSPredicate` to filter part of the array, and then looping again to find something else.  Why not just use the predicate to do both?

```
BOOL IsWordOf(NSString* myString, NSString* myWord)
{
    NSMutableCharacterSet *separators = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
    [separators formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *parse_array = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];

    NSPredicate *search = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.length > 0 AND SELF ==[cd] %@", myWord];
    NSArray *filtered = [parse_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:search];
    return [filtered count] > 0;   
}
```